# Knockout TreeView WebApi Binding Reccursive Array

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I have tree like this:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/tree.js"></script>

<script type="text/html" id="tree-node">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>

        <div>
            <ul data-bind="template: {name: 'tree-node', foreach: Children}"></ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</script>

<ul data-bind="template: {name: 'tree-node', foreach: tree}"></ul>
```

ViewModel:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
var self = this;
self.tree = ko.observableArray([]);

self.getTree = function() {
    $.get('/api/tree', 'json', function(data) {
        self.tree(data);
    });
}.bind(self);

};

var vm = new ViewModel();
vm.getTree();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Api:

```
public List<Objects> Get()
{
    ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    return ctx.Objects.ToList().Where(z=>z.Parent==null).ToList();
}
```

Objects contains children, which must be binded to tree:

```
public class Objects
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; } 
    public virtual Objects Parent { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<Objects> Children { get; set; }
}
```

And in the end i get nothing.
I look viewmodel at Knockoutjs context debugger, and i see my data. But it is not rendered on page. Why?

Comment: Any errors in the console? What's the value of `data` in the /api/tree callback?

Comment: you have to use self everywhere in vm as you declared `var self=this` and  use something like this `self.A=function(){//code}.bind(self)` where inner self represents root observable

Comment: data is [[object Object]]. no errors in console.

Comment: changed this to self, no effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tree` is an array, so you should define it as:

```
self.tree = ko.observableArray([]);
```

The problem comes from the parent `ul` binding :

```
<ul data-bind="template: {name: 'tree-node', data: tree}"></ul>
```

It will render the template only once with `data=tree` ==> this will set the template context as the `tree` array, which does not have `Name` or `Children` properties. These properties belong to the elements inside this array. So you have to change the binding to:

```
<ul data-bind="template: {name: 'tree-node', foreach: tree}"></ul>
```

Comment: made your changes, edited post. but no effect again.

Comment: Working here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyq6n35/1/). Are you sure you are receiving data from server, and it's an array of objects?

Comment: my falt, called knockout code too soon. checked as answer. thx.

Comment: @manji i'm sometimes amused why use `template` rather go with`foreach` on top of `ul` and inside so on which is more clear to understand . does template binding gives ant advantage over the other?

Comment: @supercool, the example here of recursive binding cannot be done with a simple `foreach` binding. As you can see inside the template script, the template itself is re-rendered when appling the binding to children. Then those children when bound, if they also have children, the same template will be applied again, and so on.

Comment: `the template itself is re-rendered` my bad i missed to notice same `tree-node` there .so definitely  in this case this will be most useful . Are there more scenarios template comes in handy over `foreach` . any link is appreciated mate (if happened to be more)

Comment: `template` and `foreach` bindings each have its usage. It happens that a template accepts a `foreach` extension, so that it's applied to an array of objects which is equivalent to have a `foreach` enclosing a static template. The main goal of templates is to reuse a chunk of html tags in different places in the same page => no duplication.